# Selenium: Cant click first item in dropdown

Tags: java, html, selenium

In my web page I want to click on the txtbox which will drop down a list, and then click on the first option. I can't use the selector option since the it isn't a select type. So I am using the Action in selenium to move my mouse to click. When in the web page if I click over the textbox the dropdown will list the items. But in my selenium code it can find the txtbox element, but when I click it, it can't element in the list. I don't think the list appears when I click on the txtbox. Heres my current code:

```
Webelement txtbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lob\"]"));
Webelement inpt =driver.findElement
        (By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]"));

mouseHoverAction(txtbox); 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(inpt));                 
Utils.mouseHoverAction(inpt);

 public static void mouseHoverAction(WebElement mainElement){
        
         Actions action = new Actions(driver);
         action.moveToElement(mainElement).perform();
         action.click();
         action.perform();
         Log.info("Click action is performed on the selected Product Type");
     }
```

In my Log file it never says that the click action was performed but it does say the textbox was found.

**Here is the HTML before I click on textbox:**

```html
<div class="ant-select margin___3sLIj ant-select-lg ant-select-single 
ant-select-show-arrow" name="lineOfBusiness" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="ant-select-selector">
    <span class="ant-select-selection-search">
       <input id="lob" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input"
       role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="lob_list" aria-autocomplete="list" 
       aria-controls="lob_list" aria-activedescendant="lob_list_0" 
       readonly="" unselectable="on" value="" style="opacity: 0;" aria-expanded="false">
      </span>
      <span class="ant-select-selection-placeholder">Please select one
     </span>
  </div>
>
```

**Here is HTML after I click drop down and insepct first element in list "Business Enablement"**

```html
<div class="ant-select-dropdown ant-select-dropdown-placement-bottomLeft  
ant-select-dropdown-hidden" style="min-width: 205px; width: 205px; 
left: 182.984px; top: 614.984px;">
<div>  
  <div role="listbox" id="lob_list" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div aria-label="Business Enablement" role="option" 
    id="lob_list_0" aria-selected="false">Business Enablement</div>
    <div aria-label="Capital Markets" role="option" 
    id="lob_list_1" aria-selected="false">Capital Markets</div>
 </div>
  <div class="" style="height: 256px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-anchor: none;">
    <div style="height: 480px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; transform: translateY(0px); 
      position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px;"><div aria-selected="false" 
      class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option ant-select-item-option-active">
        <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Business Enablement
        </div>
        <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" 
        style="user-select: none;"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Capital Markets
        </div>
        <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" 
        style="user-select: none;"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Caribbean Banking
        </div>
        <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" 
        style="user-select: none;"></span>
       </div>
       <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Cloud
        </div>
        <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" 
        style="user-select: none;"></span>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**I need help selecting "Business Enablment"**

Extra Pics

[image: What dropdown look like on webpage. I want to select first option]

[image: Html page source before dropdown is clicked]

Comment: I was facing same issue and got through with clicking the input (id 'lob' in your case) to appear all the options and getting the options as List of WebElement found by relative xpath.

Comment: Can you share url of this to check? or i can provide code segments of ggogle search result and pick 1 st result from list

Comment: @JustinLambert I can't provide the URL since you wouldn't be able to access it

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can attempt to try it -

1. Click the dropdown
2. Right click on the first element of the dropdown, inspect . After the developer option is open, right click on that element, copy full xpath. Now you will need to tweak the xpath to capture everything from the list. Sometimes you can just use //li and get content of the list or sometimes you will have to add * to either table, tr depending on the xpath
3. Once you get the xpath to capture the list, store it in List

   List brand = driver.findElements(By.xpath("use your custom xpath"));
4. Iterate through the list and store the text
5. Search for the value you want to click
6. Click the element when you find

This is one of the method I have written for my project

```
public void selectBrand(String Brand) {

        List<WebElement> brand = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li"));// this will store all elements from brands dropdown, again you will need to use your custom xpath 

        for (WebElement brandlist : brand)

        {

            String brandName = brandlist.getText();// store all text from dropdown

            if (brandName.length() > 1) {
                if (brandName.contains(Brand))// search for the value to click 

                {
                    brandlist.click();// click 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```